# drag and drop feature in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to use drag and drop feature in my application, I downloaded the drag and drop module which can be found here: https://github.com/a5hik/ng-sortable , I need to use a simple example exactly like this: 
http://a5hik.github.io/ng-sortable/#/kanban
I don't know how to use it, If I need to download another thing. 
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: I think you could try this module : https://github.com/marceljuenemann/angular-drag-and-drop-lists I use it and he works well.

Comment: @FlorianB please I did with the exemple you show me, and I haven't the drag and drop effect, I don't know what's a mistake, please help me :( can you please take a look in what I did, I put it in github that you can see github.com/alyssaMel/angular.git thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update :** Here is simple working example : [**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/TuLyJaTA6AAra9oQGzfw?p=preview)

Just follow the steps which this [**link mentioend.**](https://github.com/a5hik/ng-sortable)

**Step 1 :** Make sure to load the scripts in your html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/ng-sortable.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dist/ng-sortable.min.css">

<!-- OPTIONAL: default style -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dist/ng-sortable.style.min.css">
```

**Step 2 :** And Inject the sortable module as dependency

```
angular.module('xyzApp', ['as.sortable', '....']);
```

**Step 3 :** Invoke the Directives using below html structure

**Html**

```
<ul data-as-sortable="board.dragControlListeners" data-ng-model="items">
   <li data-ng-repeat="item in items" data-as-sortable-item>
      <div data-as-sortable-item-handle></div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

**Step 4 :** Define your callbacks in the invoking controller

**JS**

```
$scope.dragControlListeners = {
    accept: function (sourceItemHandleScope, destSortableScope) {return boolean}//override to determine drag is allowed or not. default is true.
    itemMoved: function (event) {//Do what you want},
    orderChanged: function(event) {//Do what you want},
    containment: '#board'//optional param.
    clone: true //optional param for clone feature.
    allowDuplicates: false //optional param allows duplicates to be dropped.
};

$scope.dragControlListeners1 = {
        containment: '#board'//optional param.
        allowDuplicates: true //optional param allows duplicates to be dropped.
};
```

And you can inspect the exact example you have mentioned above by using `F12` Key.

[image]

[image]

Comment: PS: thank you for replying @Sampath
I tried to follow instructions but I still haven't the drag and drop effect 
https://github.com/alyssaMel/dragAndDrop.git
Can you tike a look of what I did please and thanks in advance

Comment: can't you create a `plunker` for this ?

Comment: what's a plunker please?? I didn't understand

Comment: Plunker is an online community for creating, collaborating on and sharing your web development ideas.https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview

Comment: thank you for your help brother
I put it on plunker, https://plnkr.co/edit/T52QqdP7EXOZDwFTMKfe?p=preview this is a link and in app.js I think that I haven't complete or I made a mistake in

Comment: please help me, I'm blocked :(

Comment: if you go to console window then you can see lot of error messages no ?

Comment: Please see this plunker url where how to set the angular apis and others.You have to give it from `CDN` or create same file name on the plunker and copy/paste that api's source code into that file. https://plnkr.co/edit/OjGm5zyraAkWaIRjhZO1

Comment: I changed url and still have the same problem, in app.js I have this:  $scope.dragControlListeners = { accept: function (sourceItemHandleScope, destSortableScope) {return boolean},//override to determine drag is allowed or not. default is true.
    itemMoved: function (event) {}, 
    orderChanged: function(event) {} ,
    containment: '#board',
    clone: true ,
    allowDuplicates: false //optional param allows duplicates to be dropped.}; 
I don't know if I should modify something there, please take a look 
https://plnkr.co/edit/T52QqdP7EXOZDwFTMKfe?p=preview

Comment: Please see the `Update` section.

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful try using this module

```
http://angular-dragdrop.github.io/angular-dragdrop/
```